# Request body is an empty object / axios / express

Tags: vue.js, express

When making a get request with axios like:

```
  getInformation(name) {
    var data = {
      sName: name
    };
    
    return instance
      .get('/getSeason/', data)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
```

and accessing the request body I get an empty object.
Body-Parser is used in app.js. When making the request with query strings I can read the req.query.
Content type is set to: `'Content-Type': 'application/json',`

Comment: What is `instance`?

Comment: You can't pass a request body when using GET method. You can only do that for POST, PUT, and PATCH

Comment: @jstarnate Thank you! Didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`axios.get` function's second parameter refers to options configuration. You cannot send data in axios.get a request in the second parameter. Refer [axios.get signature](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config).